# Run custom script after homestead provision

Tags: laravel, vagrant, virtual-machine, homestead

I want to run custom scripts on my VM after running `homestead provision`. The `after.sh` provided with homestead runs all commands as `sudo` which in turn runs relative to the root directory and with admin privileges.

**Is there a way for me to utilize the `after.sh` as a non-admin?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can edit the Vagrantfile, after the part where you see

```
if File.exists? afterScriptPath then
    config.vm.provision "shell", path: afterScriptPath
end
```

you can add your own provisioning such as

```
config.vm.provision "shell", path: confDir + "/afterNonRoot.sh", privileged: false
```

and create a `afterNonRoot.sh` script file with the command you want to run. Save the file next to the default `after.sh`

Adding the `privileged: false` makes sure the script will be run as your vagrant user with non admin privileges

If you do not want to change anything in the way vagrant/homestead runs the script, the only thing that I can think of is to still run the `after.sh` as `root` user but you can run commands as `su -u vagrant -c xxx` where xxx is the command you want to execute

Comment: I am actually looking for a way where I can stay out of the `composer/vendor` directory, thats where the `VagrantFile` is stored

Comment: ok you will not have much choice, run command as `su -u vagrant -c command`